# How to get the index or variable length of a value using perl(something like dynamic list length of java)?

Tags: perl

I have 2 outputs:-

```
7: ib1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP>    
9: bondib0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

Using perl I want to get the substr ib1 and bondib0.
Currently if I set

```
substr($line,3,3); this will return ib1
substr($line,3,7); this will return bondib0
```

I want to have a single substr for above, how to do that?

Something like substr($line,3,index($line,":"));

Please let me know how can i have dynamic value for 3 and 7 indexs above it is coming because of lengths of values are different.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the expected output is?

Comment: its output should be dynamic like if i give arr[1] = ib0 and arr[2] = bondib0 without any extra spaces or characters

Answer (score 5):

Your approach to use `substr` and `index` should work. However, there are two other ways to do this.

The easier one is to use a regular expression and do a pattern match.

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ m/: ([^:]+):/) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
7: ib1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP>    
9: bondib0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

This will match a string on a colon `:` and a space , and then capture everything that is not a colon, until it encounters another colon. See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oLiAKu/1) for an explanation, and take a look at [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a gentle introduction to regex.

An alternative would be to use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) on a colon and a space. There are only two of them there.

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    ( undef, my $interface ) = split /: /, $line;
    print $interface;
}

__DATA__
7: ib1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP>    
9: bondib0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

It will break the string into pieces on `": "`, discard the first part, save the second and discard the rest.

However the regex solution is better.

Answer (score -1):

To generalise, one Solution I can figure out is below:-

```
 my $pindex = rindex($line,":");
 $str = substr($line,3,$pindex-3);
```

This solves the purpose by reading each character.